# How to increase the width of a gt table in a Rmarkdown pdf document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

Hi and thanks for reading me

Im making a pdf document with a table and and I would like to increase the width of the table on the page, but no command has worked for me so far. Does anyone know what command to use to fix that?

The Rmarkdown code is the following:

````
---
title: "ejemplo"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
papersize: a4
classoption: landscape
geometry: "left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
 
 
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} 
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in][l]{#1}      
}


```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=900}
library(gt)

data <- datasets::iris

data |> 
  head(10) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Other = " "
  ) |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_options(table.width = pct(200),
              container.width = 900
              )
```

\mbox{}
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
\SignatureAndDate{Nombre y Firma del Operador}
\end{flushright}
````

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(gt)
gt(mtcars) %>% tab_options(., container.width = 500, container.height = 500)
```

or based on your preferred size

````
  ```{r cars}
    library(gt)
    gt(mtcars) %>% tab_options(., container.width = 500, container.height = 1000)
    ```
````